# Send already displayed emails with VBA-Excel

Tags: vba, excel

### Display emails and then send them automaticly

I have made a loop with different cases for different emails. I used the basic form

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .To = 'Range of addreesses
    .CC = 'Other addresses
    .Subject = 'Different Subjects
    .Body = 'Body
    .Display
End With
```

And all works fine but am wondering if after checking all the info is correct there's a way to send them all at the same time.

I have tried making an array of *OutMail* but I cannot make it to work, I had in mind something like this:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(arrayMails)
arrayMails[i].Send
Next i
```

Hope you can help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks good on first glance... do you have an error message?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `arrayMails(i).Send`?

Answer (score 0):

@BigBen Yes it should

Also, I find a way hope I can help someone

```
ReDim arrayMails(lenght) = Outlook.MailItem
```

and every time I create and an email I did

```
arrayMails(i) = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Thank you for the answers!